# Nodejs: Getting plain text from HTML but retaining ordered and unordered lists

Tags: html, node.js

I am attempting to obtain the plain text from a piece of HTML code but would like to retain the numberings of from the ordered or unordered list. So far, libraries such as [node-html-parser](https://github.com/taoqf/node-html-parser) and [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) do not retain those information.

Meaning to say, given a HTML like so:

```html
<ol>
        <li>Number 1
            <ol style="list-style-type: lower-alpha;">
                <li>Number a</li>
                <li>Number b</li>
            </ol>
        </li>
    
        <li>Number 2
            <ol style="list-style-type: lower-alpha;">
                <li>Number a
                    <ol style="list-style-type: lower-roman;">
                        <li>Number i</li>
                        <li>Number ii</li>
                    </ol>
                </li>
                <li>Number b</li>
                <li>Number c</li>
            </ol>
        </li>
    </ol>
```

I would like to obtain:

```
1. Number 1
   a. Number a
   b. Number b
2. Number 2
   a. Number a
      i. Number i
      ii. Number ii
   b. Number b
   c. Number c
```

I write in Nodejs.

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: @Seblor using `.getText()` and `.text`, `.rawText` from `cheerio` and `node-html-parser` libraries

Comment: That is probably something you will have to write yourself then, by actually looping over the HTML structure.

Comment: In your posts, please try to refrain from chatty material, pleading for assistance, and abbreviated txtspk. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
    import {
    parse
    } from 'node-html-parser';
    var html = `<ol>
    <li>Number 1
     <ol style="list-style-type: lower-alpha;">
         <li>Number a</li>
         <li>Number b</li>
     </ol>
  </li>
<li>Number 2
    <ol style="list-style-type: lower-alpha;">
        <li>Number a
            <ol style="list-style-type: lower-roman;">
                <li>Number i</li>
                <li>Number ii</li>
            </ol>
        </li>
        <li>Number b</li>
        <li>Number c</li>
    </ol>
</li>
</ol>`
const root = parse(html);

var children = root.querySelector('ol')
var m = children.innerHTML
var lis = parse(m)
var m = lis.text
console.log(JSON.stringify(m))
```

output will be

```
Number 1 
     
        Number a 
        Number b 
     
 
Number 2 
     
        Number a 
             
                Number i 
                Number ii 
             
         
        Number b 
        Number c
```